Crack etherem validator keystore
I am trying to move my validator to an new and better device, but midway I realized I forgot the password used to create the keystore :(
I know parts of it, so I think I can crack it using hashcat like suggested in https://stealthsploit.com/2017/06/12/ethereum-wallet-cracking/
However, the new keystore V4 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2335) has a different format, for example:
{
    "crypto": {
        "kdf": {
            "function": "scrypt",
            "params": {
                "dklen": 32,
                "n": 262144,
                "p": 1,
                "r": 8,
                "salt": "d4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"
            },
            "message": ""
        },
        "checksum": {
            "function": "sha256",
            "params": {},
            "message": "d2217fe5f3e9a1e34581ef8a78f7c9928e436d36dacc5e846690a5581e8ea484"
        },
        "cipher": {
            "function": "aes-128-ctr",
            "params": {
                "iv": "264daa3f303d7259501c93d997d84fe6"
            },
            "message": "06ae90d55fe0a6e9c5c3bc5b170827b2e5cce3929ed3f116c2811e6366dfe20f"
        }
    },
    "description": "This is a test keystore that uses scrypt to secure the secret.",
    "pubkey": "9612d7a727c9d0a22e185a1c768478dfe919cada9266988cb32359c11f2b7b27f4ae4040902382ae2910c15e2b420d07",
    "path": "m/12381/60/3141592653/589793238",
    "uuid": "1d85ae20-35c5-4611-98e8-aa14a633906f",
    "version": 4
}

So the hashcat command doesn't work:
hashcat -m15700 -a0 crackme.txt dic1.txt   --status --status-timer=5 -w3 --potfile-disable -o result.txt

I tried using checksum.message in the place of MAC, but no luck.
I am not sure if I am formatting the parameters wrong, or we need a new hashtype (https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat), because 15700 doesn't work.
Does anyone have any ideas how to use hashcat to crack an ethereum keystore v4?

copy and paste your question into chatGpt
